# Cannot start the Pi - error writing RiscOS blob

Tags: pi-3, riscos

I'm using Raspberry Pi Model B. I've formatted my SD card with SDFormatter, copied NOOBS files onto it and started the Pi. Then it starts setting everything up and in one point it gets this "error writing RiscOS blob".
I had no luck in googling the problem so I hope that some of you can help me fix this, please.

Comment: Noobs is just an installer - which operating system are you wanting to install? RiscOS?

Comment: @CoderMike The thing is I just got the Pi so I don't have anything specific. I want to go with Raspbian. I need Mathematica software which is bundled with NOOBS and it's free to use but I didn't even get to the screen to select which OS I want to install. Error appeared before that screen.

Comment: As per other comments NOOBS is more trouble than it is worth if what you want to do is use Raspbian.  Just use Raspbian.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Download 'Raspbian with Desktop' (no need to unzip) from https://www.raspberrypi.org/downloads/raspbian/

Flash to sd card using Etcher https://www.balena.io/etcher/

Place sd card in the Pi and turn on.

Once Raspbian is up and running you can use 'Recommended Software' under Preferences to install Mathematica.